# Movement restriction on GridLayout to only adjacent grid buttons

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, point

I am making a game where move across a gridlayout of jbuttons, only allowing movement to adjacent grid jbuttons. The goal is to try and make it to the topleft (From the btm right). I think this is all that is relevant:

//Here is my method to determine whether it is a valid move (i dont want you to be      able to move anywhere but adjacent spots

```
    public boolean goodMove(int x, int y) {

    int val = Math.abs(current.x - x) + Math.abs(current.y - y);

    return val == 1;
}
```

//Here is the logic in the actionlister, a big if else loop that is now referencing only the jbuttons in my gridlayout (the game panel)

```
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    JButton clicked = (JButton) e.getSource();

    if (clicked == SHOWMINES) {

        if (SHOWMINES.getText().equals("Show Mines")) {
            showMines();
            SHOWMINES.setText("Hide Mines");
        } else {
            hideMines();
        }
    } else {
        if (clicked == NEWGAME) {
            newGame();
        } else {
            if (clicked == SHOWPATH) {
                if (SHOWPATH.getText().equals("Show Path")) {
                    showPath();
                    SHOWPATH.setText("Hide Path");
                } else {
                    hidePath();
                }
            } else {
                if (clicked == OKAY) {
                    resetGridSize(Integer.parseInt(gridSizeInput.getText()));
                    newGame();
                } else {

                }
                int gs = Integer.parseInt(gridSizeInput.getText());
                for (int i = 0; i < gs - 1; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < gs - 1; j++) {
                        if (clicked == grid[i][j]) {
                            if (goodMove(i, j)) {//debug tester ,this is where the problem is.
                                System.out.println("TEST");
                                current = new Point(i, j);
                                grid[i][j].setBackground(Color.green);
                                grid[i][j].setText("=");
                            }else{System.out.println("TEST2");}
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}// end of action listener
```

Grid[][] is my array of grid buttons, gridSizeInput is the textfield that you can adjust the gridsize in.

Thanks in advance (I'm new to programming, so keep it simple if you can :)

EDIT: I forgot to mention, it is not recognizing my if(goodMove()) loop, its just printing out TWO for my else.

EDIT: My question is why is not working, no buttons will are be recognized as clicked in my grid, I guess I am asking to see if something I have written is glaringly obviously wrong. thanks.

EDIT: Okay here is my entire action listener for all my buttons. This is my first post, sorry I am not more helpful- let me know if anything else I can add.

Comment: It's undeclared at the top, then in my newGame() method I make it current = new Point(gridSize - 1, gridSize - 1);

Comment: I would use a debugger and print out the values of current and the clicked grid button's i and j, or use a debugger. Your first and main goal right now is to first isolate your error, and this must be done before anything else can be.

Comment: When I print out my current, the point always prints out the size of the grid, for a 10x10, its 9,9 regardless of which button i select.

Comment: The value of my i and j seem to be correct, selecting a button will print out the corresponding row or column # for the selected btn

Comment: I do not call goodMove() anywhere in the doc except in that if loop at the btm (does that even count?) I suppose it behaves as I think it should, the logic looks good in it, but as usual, I have difficulty implementing everything correctly.

Comment: If I'm in a similar situation, I test each method to make sure it's being called where and when I think it's being called, that all my variable values are what I expect them to be. So either use a debugger or a lot of println statements to test this code up and down, back and forth til you isolate your error.

Comment: Okay thanks, I'll work on that for a bit and come back. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds good. We'll be here.

Comment: Please see edit to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem may be as simple as your not extending your for loops out far enough. Try changing this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < gs - 1; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < gs - 1; j++) {
```

to this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < gs; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < gs; j++) {
```

---

**Edit**
This was the minimal code example that I created to test the concept:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Foo extends JPanel {
   public static final int GRID_SIZE = 10;
   private Point current;
   private JButton[][] grid;

   public Foo() {
      ButtonListener listener = new ButtonListener();
      setLayout(new GridLayout(GRID_SIZE, GRID_SIZE));
      grid = new JButton[GRID_SIZE][GRID_SIZE];
      for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
            grid[i][j] = new JButton("   ");
            grid[i][j].addActionListener(listener);
            add(grid[i][j]);
         }
      }

      current = new Point(GRID_SIZE - 1, GRID_SIZE - 1);
   }

   private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         JButton clicked = (JButton) e.getSource();
         // !! int gs = Integer.parseInt(gridSizeInput.getText());
         int gs = GRID_SIZE;
         // !! for (int i = 0; i < gs - 1; i++) {
         // for (int j = 0; j < gs - 1; j++) {
         for (int i = 0; i < gs; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < gs; j++) {

               if (clicked == grid[i][j]) {
                  if (goodMove(i, j)) {
                     System.out.println("TEST");
                     current = new Point(i, j);
                     grid[i][j].setBackground(Color.green);
                     grid[i][j].setText("=");
                  } else {
                     System.out.println("TEST2");
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }

   public boolean goodMove(int x, int y) {
      int val = Math.abs(current.x - x) + Math.abs(current.y - y);
      return val == 1;
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      Foo mainPanel = new Foo();
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Foo");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: through your recommendations, I was able to isolate the problem and figure out other things that were going on with my Point current, thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Consuela: glad you're project is moving forward. Best of luck!